# where is the _SYS_AFL schema and the apriori_lite function in hana sps10?

Tags: hana

I have installled it 
when I run this
SELECT * FROM "SYS"."AFL_FUNCTIONS" WHERE AREA_NAME = 'AFLPAL';
I see the _sys_afl schema listed but no apriori_lite? is renamed or what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions had been renamed to APRIORULE and LITEAPRIORIRULE in SPS 10. That's easy to find in the SAP HANA Predictive Analysis Library (PAL) documentation.